# Grep for multiple values in line and output MULTIPLE values ONLY

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

Suppose we have key value pairs like:

```
ts=2017-06-27-19-59-13-036 | result=SUCCESS | requestId=xyz | elapsed=49
```

How can I output multiple key-value pairs; suppose result  & elapsed in above line [ search for keys based on keyname not on location]

I wanted output something like:
result=SUCCESS | elapsed=49

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep -oP`:

```
s='ts=2017-06-27-19-59-13-036 | result=SUCCESS | requestId=xyz | elapsed=49'

grep -oP '(result|elapsed)=\S+' <<< "$s"

result=SUCCESS
elapsed=49
```

Or using `gnu awk`:

```
awk -F= -v RS=' \\| |\n' '$1 ~ /^(result|elapsed)$/' <<< "$s"

result=SUCCESS
elapsed=49
```

Comment: I wanted output of two keys and values

Comment: I updated my answer. `\S` means match any non-whitespace character.

Comment: anubhava your output is only printing one key-value pair; how can we print both KV pairs ?

Comment: It is printing both pairs as shown in output there are 2 pairs: `result=SUCCESS` and 
`elapsed=49`

Comment: Thanks.. is it possible to get it printed on same line separated by like a pipe

Comment: Using awk you can do: `awk -F= -v RS=' \\| |\n' '$1 ~ /^(result|elapsed)$/' ORS='|' <<< "$s"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
ts=2017-06-27-19-59-13-036 | result=SUCCESS | requestId=xyz | elapsed=49
```

To get key=value pairs try `egrep`

```
$ egrep -o '[a-z]*[A-Z]*[a-z]*=([0-9-]*|[A-Z]*|[a-z]*)' file
ts=2017-06-27-19-59-13-036
result=SUCCESS
requestId=xyz
elapsed=49
```